# Loading an image in a button to be displayed in a button/image holder or rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, image, visual-studio-2013, buttonclick

I am struggling with a button click method.
It's purpose is to make an image which is in a button (the buttons border is around the image) show in a button/image holder or rectangle?

So what I am trying to do is, click the button 1 and the image in button one shows in button/image holder or rectangle 2..

Any suggestions? I am using C# 2013

```
private void btnEarthShaker_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (btnEarthShaker.Click = true) ; // click has an error - Routedeventhandler problem
    {
        btnBAN1.show("1Earthshaker.png"); //show does not contain a definition
    }
}
```

Look guys, I am really new to programming... So I honestly have no idea what to do next. I tried this:

```
private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox1.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);  
    }
}
```

Comment: What did u try so far? Please provide some code

Comment: What is this: WinForms or WPF or ASP? What is your 'rectangle' - a Panel?? Another Button??? I suggest you read a little on how to ask questions here..

Comment: You meant this, you are having button and rectangle area..Once you click the button, It should open the filedialog and allow the user to choose the image and finally shows the respective image in the rectangle area..Am I right?  Just be clear with your sentences..very convoluted

Comment: Yes. I'd like to click the button, and the same image that is in it must show in the rectangle. I'd like it to show in another button though.

Comment: I'd like it to show in another button though????Can you explain the sentence..What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's really easy to understand. Forget the rectangle (that was my first choice to hold the image). I have a button... click the button... the image in that button is then displayed in another button.

button one has an image in it, button two doesnt.
click button one, the image in button one is then displayed in button two.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you code, because you should at least figure out "some" of it.

The thing to know here, is that both controls has an "image" property... and one's image property, can be set by setting it equal to the other's image property...